# property value injection into spring beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, inversion-of-control

i want to know why `@Value` property injection works on classes with `@Service` annotation but not on classes with `@Bean` within `@Configuration` annotated class.

Works means that the property value is not null.

This value is also injected into two other service which i see during debugging in `DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency`. But i dont see the bean `WebserviceEndpoint`.

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class WebserviceConfig {

   // do some configuration stuff

   @Bean
   public IWebserviceEndpoint webserviceEndpoint() {
      return new WebserviceEndpoint();
   }

}
```

**Webservice interface**

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://de.example/", name = "IWebservice")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface IWebserviceEndpoint {
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "response", targetNamespace = "http://de.example/", partName = "parameters")
    public Response callWebservice(@WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "request", targetNamespace = "http://de.example/") Request request) throws RequestFault;
}
```

**Webservice class**

```
public class WebserviceEndpoint implements IWebserviceEndpoint {

   @Value("${value.from.property}")
   private String propertyValue;

}
```

**application.yml**

```
value:
 from:
  property: property-value
```

When does the injection of @Value happen in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `propertyValue` is null because Spring injects value after bean's creation.
So when you do:

```
@Bean
public IWebserviceEndpoint webserviceEndpoint() {
  return new WebserviceEndpoint();
}
```

Spring creates a new instance with `propertyValue=null`. 
You can initialize your instance attribue with `@ConfigurationProperties`

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix=...)
public IWebserviceEndpoint webserviceEndpoint() {
   return new WebserviceEndpoint();
}
```

Note that `propertyValue` should have a setter.

You have several ways to solve this problem, usually it's good to centralize properties in one utils class.

```
@Component
public class Configs {
  @Value("${propery}"
  String property;

  String getProperty(){ 
    return property;
  }
}
```

And then:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix=...)
public IWebserviceEndpoint webserviceEndpoint() {
    WebserviceEndpoint we = new WebserviceEndpoint();
    we.setProperty(configs.getProperty())
   return we;
}
```

Again there are many many different ways to solve this problem